# gotoAnPlay() returns to first frame after being called twice with same number

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs6

I have two `keyframes` in my scene. In the first one, I have the following code:

```
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;

stop();
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, foo);

function foo(event:KeyboardEvent):void {
    gotoAndPlay(2);
}
```

In the second one, I have the following code:

```
stop();
```

On the first time I press a key, the scene goes to frame 2 as expected. But on the second time, it goes to frame 1.

Also, if I use `gotoAndStop` instead of `gotoAndPlay`, the scene always goes to frame 2.

Anyone knows the reason behind this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it's defined by Adobe, [`gotoAndPlay()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/MovieClip.html#gotoAndplay%28%29)

> Starts playing the SWF file at the specified frame ...

So if you are in the second frame of your scene, when you do `gotoAndPlay(2)` it has the same action as a simple `play()`, that's why you will be back to your first frame. And it's the same behavior with `gotoAndStop(2)` when it's executed in the second frame, it's equal to a simple `stop()`.

**Conclusion :**

- `gotoAndPlay()` when it's called from a frame and to go and play the same frame, it's equal to a simple `play()`.
- `gotoAndStop()` when it's called from a frame and to go and stop the same frame, it's equal to a simple `stop()`.

Hope that can help.

Comment: I think the relevant fact here (which I discovered right before posting this reply) is that, in my case, when calling `gotoAndPlay(2)` in frame 2, the code in frame 2 doesn't run, thus it doesn't stop. But that's a strange behaviour to me, since when `gotoAndPlay(x)` is called from frame y, the code in frame x runs. So I would expect that if `gotoAndPlay(x)` is called from frame x, the code in frame x would run.

Comment: It's executed when you have just coming from the 1st frame ! You are stopped in the 2nd frame ! It's like a break in the second frame and then ... continue ...